# How can I detect/remove special characters from this short text file?

Tags: applescript, cat, head

This is the contents of a short text file created by an AppleScript written by someone else:

```
Search time: Sunday April 28, 2019 at 07:21:07
Search complete. Nothing found.
```

But, when I use cat I get the following:

```
MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ cat /Users/mnewman/Desktop/DetectX_Search.txt
MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ ng found.019 at 07:21:07
```

When I look at the file in BBEdit and turn ON "show invisibles" I only see spaces and newlines.

The file looks normal in nano.

I want to read the first line of the file into a variable but nothing works:

```
MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ read -r growlm < /Users/mnewman/Desktop/DetectX_Search.txt
MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ echo $growlm
Search complete. Nothing found.2019 at 07:21:07

MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ growlm="$(head -1 /Users/mnewman/Desktop/DetectX_Search.txt)"
MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ echo $growlm
Search complete. Nothing found.2019 at 07:21:07

MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ file /Users/mnewman/Desktop/DetectX_Search.txt
/Users/mnewman/Desktop/DetectX_Search.txt: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ cat /Users/mnewman/Desktop/DetectX_Search.txt | od -c
0000000    S   e   a   r   c   h       t   i   m   e   :       S   u   n
0000020    d   a   y   ,       A   p   r   i   l       2   8   ,       2
0000040    0   1   9       a   t       0   9   :   3   9   :   1   7  \r
0000060    S   e   a   r   c   h       c   o   m   p   l   e   t   e   .
0000100        N   o   t   h   i   n   g       f   o   u   n   d   .  \r
0000120
```

Comment: Your question is misleading.  `\r` is return; newline is `\n`.  As you seem to understand (from your self-answer), the file does *not* contain any newlines.

Comment: I was initially deceived by the fact that BBEdit seems to use the same character ("¬") to represent both return and newline.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked:

```
cat DetectX_Search.txt | tr '\r' '\n' > DetectX.txt

MrMuscle:bin mnewman$ cat DetectX.txt
Search time: Sunday, April 28, 2019 at 10:40:35
Search complete. Nothing found.
```